# OrientDB Studio - Graph Editor

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

Accessing Graph Editor with a read user 'appreader' throws the exception for read permission on OUser.

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSecurityAccessException: User 'appreader' does not have permission to execute the operation 'Read' against the resource: ResourceGeneric [name=CLASS, legacyName=database.class].ouser DB name="OPSDB"
```

Studio version : 2.2
OrientDB version : 2.2.31

Why does the user needs read permission on Ouser to perform graph operations, If I provide read access to the user, he is able to do a select on OUser and see the passwords for other users as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The user with reader permissions can not access OUser table to get passwords due to security reasons. Unfortunately it's not possible to access graph operations for such user.